# jquery calculate BMI

Tags: javascript, jquery

I stuck to this problem. I want to calculate body BMI.

My HTML - every row `<tr>` is created dynamically by PHP.

```
     <tbody>        
     <tr id="person_bmi">
        <td>Jack</td>
        <td><input name="weight" type="text" class="span1" id="weight" maxlength="5"></td>
        <td><input name="height" type="text" class="span1" id="height" maxlength="5"></td>
        <td><input name="bmi" type="text" class="span1" id="bmi" readonly></td>       
      </tr>

    <tr id="person_bmi">
        <td>Michael</td>
        <td><input name="weight" type="text" class="span1" id="weight" maxlength="5"></td>
        <td><input name="height" type="text" class="span1" id="height" maxlength="5"></td>
        <td><input name="bmi" type="text" class="span1" id="bmi" readonly></td>       
      </tr>

      //and so on...
</tbody>
```

What I try to achieve is every person `Jack`, `Michael`, `so on..` will have their own BMI values in `#bmi` textfield after calculated their own `$weight/($height*100/$height*100)` value. I try to create my own code but its not make sense..

```
$("#weight, #height").keyup(function(){
    var $weight= $("#weight").val();
    var $height= $("#height").val();
    var $bmi = $weight/($height/100*$height/100);

    $("#bmi").val(parseInt($bmi));
});
```

Can someone show me the way? Thanks

Comment: Why do you prefix your non-jQuery variables with `$`?! Besides that, IDs have to be **unique**.

Comment: influenced by PHP I presume..  so I can quickly identified JS variables.. hope its not bad practiced..

Comment: Well, it is. Especially in jQuery-based code people expect a variable prefixed with `$` to contain a jQuery object (and even this is a questionable code style - but common enough to not complain about it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the duplicate IDs and use `class="weight"`, `class="height"` and `class="bmi"` instead. Then you can use the following jQuery code:

```
$(".weight, .height").keyup(function() {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    var weight = parseInt(row.find('.weight').val(), 10);
    var height = parseInt(row.find('.height').val(), 10);
    var bmi = weight / (height / 100 * height / 100);
    row.find('.bmi').val(isNaN(bmi) ? '' : bmi);
});
```

If you want to allow floats for the input values, replace the two lines containing `parseInt` with these:

```
var weight = parseFloat(row.find('.weight').val());
var height = parseFloat(row.find('.height').val());
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/KStjd/

Comment: Whoever downvoted this, please explain the reason for downvoting the only correct answer.

Comment: This code worked! but I modified `row.find('.bmi').val(isNaN(bmi) ? '' : parseInt(bmi));` and adding `parseInt(bmi)` because I don't want to have floats point in my final results. Thanks @ThiefMaster!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is most likely that `val` returns strings and strings can't me multiplied or divided.  As mentioned by ThiefMaster you also can't have multiple items with the same id so change `<tr id="person_bmi">` to `<tr class="person_bmi">`

```
$(".person_bmi input").keyup(function() {
   var $parent = $(this).parent().parent();

   var weight = parseFloat($parent.find("[name='weight']").val());
   var height = parseFloat($parent.find("[name='height']").val());
   var bmi = weight/(height/100*height/100);

   $parent.find("[name='bmi']").val(bmi);
});​
```

Here is a fiddle of a full working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/uCAYF/1/

The `.find` function you see being used is "scoped" in the sense that it will only find nodes that are descended from the element it was called on.  Since it is scoped it will safely select the the input field of interest on the given row.

jQuery lets you use CSS selectors when searching for elements so you can do more than just look things up by id.  For instance, in the example above I find your input elements by their name.

Here are some good resources on the different selectors you can use and how they work:
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html

http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/

Comment: `$this` is the input field and it won't have any children (as `<input/>` is any empty tag) so your code cannot work.

Comment: Now `$this` is not used at all :p (and I think `.closest('tr')` would be better since people reading the code immediately see which element it targets)

Answer (score 1):

Please try to add unique id's:

```
var weight= parseFloat($("#person1_weight").val());
var height= parseFloat($("#person1_height").val());
var bmi = weight/(height/100*height/100);

$("#person1_bmi").val(bmi); // bmi is not an integer
```

Or the following will probably work regardless of the invalid non unique id's so you could leave them (not recommended) or take all of the id's off. It uses the input positions.

```
$("tr input:eq(0), tr input:eq(1)").keyup(function(){
    var weight= parseFloat($(this).closest('tr').find('input:eq(0)'));
    var height= parseFloat($(this).closest('tr').find('input:eq(1)'));
    var bmi = weight/(height/100*$height/100);

    $(this).closest('tr').find('input:eq(2)').val(bmi);
});
```

Comment: Won't work either since the code is broken due to the duplicate IDs.

Comment: I just realized that and updated the answer.  Realistically he should be just using a class for each one and it becomes a simple exercise.

Comment: Thanks, I added another solution that should work regardless of the non unique id's.. All he'd have to do is remove the id's and it will still actually work.  Looking for the upvote now!

Comment: Yup, that works. I'd replace `parents` with `closest` though to avoid issues in case of nested tables. And maybe store the found element int a variable to avoid traversing the DOM multiple times.

Comment: `"tr input:eq(0), tr input:eq(1)"` => `tr input:lt(2)`

Comment: Yeah, this could be more fully optimized but I'm going to leave it as is.. I just typed it out faster than my brain was working and many people dont' realize you can put multiple elements in selectors..  Appreciate the input that's for sure.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[name=weight], input[name=height").keyup(function() {
    var row = $(this).parent().parent(),
        weight = parseFloat($('input[name=weight]', row).val()),
        height = parseFloat($('input[name=height]', row).val());
    var bmi = weight / (height / 100 * height / 100);
    $('.bmi', row).val(isNaN(bmi) ? '' : bmi);
});
```

**[Working Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/ESQsn/)**

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("PutYourButtonID_Here").click(function(event){
        var weight= parseFloat($("#person1_weight").val());
        var height= parseFloat($("#person1_height").val());
        var bmi = weight/(height/100*height/100);
        $("#person1_bmi").val(bmi);
    });
});
```